# SKTUtils Errors Galore

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, sktutils

Added SKTUtils to my project and it just does not want to cooperate. I am afraid to change too much as I assumed it is coded a very specific way. Here is a few errors that I am getting and cannot figure out. Returning 20 errors then says too many errors, stopping now.

These return: **"incompatible block pointer types initializing'_strong SKTTiming Function' AKA 'float(^_strong)(float) with an expression of type 'void'(^)(float)**

**Use of undeclared identifier 'M_PI_2',M_Pi**

**Implicitly declaring library function 'sqrtf' with type float(float)**

```
SKTTimingFunction SKTTimingFunctionSineEaseIn = ^(float t) {
  return sinf((t - 1.0f) * M_PI_2) + 1.0f;
};

SKTTimingFunction SKTTimingFunctionSineEaseOut = ^(float t) {
  return sinf(t * M_PI_2);
};

SKTTimingFunction SKTTimingFunctionSineEaseInOut = ^(float t) {
  return 0.5f * (1.0f - cosf(t * M_PI));
};

SKTTimingFunction SKTTimingFunctionCircularEaseIn = ^(float t) {
  return 1.0f - sqrtf(1.0f - t * t);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an old version of SKTUtils? M_Pi is no longer used.

I just created an Xcode 7.3.1 SpriteKit project and dropped in a clean SKTUtils, no issues.

SKUtils was updated not so long ago for 7.3

https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils

Comment: That is written in swift. I added a couple of import statements and all seems to work for now.. Thanks for the response though